I am trying to write a smart contract using plutus but i am facing this problem
Couldn't match type ‘ScriptContext’ with ‘BuiltinData’
Expected type: template-haskell-2.16.0.0:Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Q
(template-haskell-2.16.0.0:Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.TExp
(PlutusTx.Code.CompiledCode
(BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> ())))
Actual type: th-compat-0.1.4:Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Compat.SpliceQ
(PlutusTx.Code.CompiledCode
(GameDatum -> GameRedeemer -> ScriptContext -> ()))
In the expression: compile [|| validateGuess ||]

Hi, for people to be able to understand your issue and help you, it would be great if you could provide more details. In what step of the process did this error occur? What are you trying to do? How does your code look like? Otherwise the likelihood of someone answering your question is very low.
